# Reduce false matches of compilations errors

Tags: compilation-mode

I am running Emacs 28.2.  After I recently upgraded from Emacs 27, I started to get a lot of false matches in the compilation buffer.  (They may have been there before, but I had to remove my customization of `compilation-error-regexp-alist` to get true errors to be matched.)

When I run a `mvn` build with `M-x compile`, lines like these from the logger are matching as errors:

```
11:17:46.123 [main] INFO c.e.m.SomeClass - Some log message
```

The 11 and 17 are underlined and a different color.  If I do `C-h k <left-click>` on that line, the help text indicates that `<mouse-2> (translated from <mouse-1>` runs `compile-goto-error`.

Since much of my compile buffer is log statements of this format, this means that click in the compilation buffer frequently brings up a dialog, asking me where the source for the file from this "error" is.

I tried to customize `compilation-error-regexp-alist` to remove a bunch of options that I don't use, but the error is still there.

Is there a good way to indicate that this format is not an error?  Or to easily figure out which symbol is causing the problem?  I've looked at `compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist`, and while I can read regex, that's a lot of complicated expressions.

I do have a lot of customizations, but when I started emacs with `emacs -Q`, the same thing happened.

The problem is definitely in the timestamp: I see the same behavior if my compile command is `echo '12:34:56.789'`

*UPDATE*

`mvn` isn't in the alist-alist, but `maven` is:

```
(insert (format "\n%s\n" (assq 'mvn compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist)))
nil
(insert (format "\n%s\n" (assq 'maven compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist)))
(maven ^\(?:\[\(?:ERROR\|\(?1:WARNING\)\|\(?2:INFO\)\)] \)?\(?3:[^
 []\(?:[^
 :]\| [^
/-]\|:[^
 []\)*\):\[\(?4:[[:digit:]]+\),\(?5:[[:digit:]]+\)]  3 4 5 (1 . 2))
```

Is there magic where `compilation-mode` reads the command and then only uses a subset of the alists?  If there is, what variables control that.  My actual compile command is `mvnFind.sh ...` where `mvnFind.sh` walks up the directory tree until it finds a pom.xml, then invokes `mvn` from that directory.  This lets me do `M-x compile` from a Java buffer and not need to open the pom or do directory gymnastics in the command.

Changing `compilation-error-regexp-alist` to `'(maven)` did fix the problem, although it does mean that compiling other languages (or probably even the project that uses grade) will lead to unrecognized real errors.

Comment: You don't need to examine all of the regexps in `compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist`, just the one that corresponds to your language. What does `(assq 'mvn compilation-error-regexp-alist-alist)` return? Best to edit your question and add that. BTW, for me that returns `nil` and that *may* be the problem you are running into, but you should take that with a large grain of salt.